# ROS Answers SE migration: Install CD

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which option is it?  when I put the number in it just says

```
pc@pc:~$ 0

0: command not found
```

pc@pc:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
pc@pc:~/catkin_ws/src$ cd ..
pc@pc:~/catkin_ws$ rosdep install pioneer3at

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource pioneer3at
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190382/install-cd/) by [HelpwithUbuntu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19984/helpwithubuntu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-16**:
So what do you think `cd` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> cd .. <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< (it simply changes the directory to the one that contains the current one. In Windows parlor: we go up, to the folder that is the parent of the current folder.) I have no idea what any of this is. I understand what CD does but not CD .. what does the two dots mean? none of the links had any info on them.

"the links" actually explained that to you (copied from [A very, very gentle introduction to the Linux Command Line](http://chrisyoung.net/prose/blog/posts/2009-11-28-very-very-gentle-introduction-linux-command-line/)):

> Let’s back up and try again:
>
> `chris@bobo:~/Desktop$ cd ..`
>
> The two dots tell us to move up a level in our directory structure.

But, just to be sure, here is another example, can't make it any simpler than this:

```
# we are currently here
pc@pc:~$ pwd
/home/pc/catkin_ws/src

# now we go one directory 'up'
pc@pc:~$ cd ..

# and now we are here
pc@pc:~$ pwd
/home/pc/catkin_ws
```

In every directory there are at least two "other" directories: "." (dot): the current directory, and ".." (double dot): the parent directory. `cd ..` tells `bash` (or whatever your shell is) to change the directory to the parent directory (whatever that currently is).

Again: I think you should first get acquainted with Linux and the command line a bit more. Otherwise you'll continue to run into issues like this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HelpwithUbuntu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19984/helpwithubuntu/) on 2014-08-16**:
I could not see the the two dots on this laptop, I never relieved that CD .. was a command, because when people are typing and want to end a sentence they use .

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-08-17**:
@HelpwithUbuntu please accept the answer using the checkmark at the left so people know it's resolved.